AWS ECS Fargate task fails with exit code 2 when triggered by EventBridge
I would like some help on how to solve or even debug the following issue.
I have setup an ECS task and an EventBridge Schedule that should trigger that task, configured via terraform. The invocation is displayed as failed in EventBridge, although I can see the task created in ECS Fargate. The task immediately stops with an Exit Code 2, mentioning that the Docker container exited, without providing any extra information.
I have also set up logging with the right permissions for the ECS task, but no logs are added, even though I think I have a correct logging configuration.
The ECS task is configured to run on a private subnet that has access to the internet, and I have managed to manually run the task via the ECS console, using the exact same private subnet and security group that I use in terraform.
I am sharing all the relevant code below after having removed the bash code that runs on the ECS instance.
Let me know if you need any more information.
Terraform Event Bridge configuration
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "ecs_log_group" {
    name = "/aws/ecs/dbt"
}

# EventBridge Rule
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "ecs_schedule" {
    name                = "ecs-dbt-schedule"
    schedule_expression = "cron(0 6-17 ? * MON-FRI *)"
}

# EventBridge Target to trigger ECS task
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "ecs_task_target" {
    rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.ecs_schedule.name
    arn = aws_ecs_cluster.fargate.arn
    role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_events_role.arn

ecs_target {
        task_count          = 1
        task_definition_arn = aws_ecs_task_definition.dbt.arn
        launch_type         = "FARGATE"
        network_configuration {
            subnets = var.subnets
            security_groups = var.security_group_ids
            assign_public_ip = false
    }
}
}

Terraform ECS configuration
# ECS Cluster
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "fargate" {
    name = "${var.environment}-dbt-cluster"
}

# ECS Task Definition
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "dbt" {
    family                   = "dbt"
    network_mode             = "awsvpc"
    requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]

    cpu    = "256"
    memory = "512"

    execution_role_arn = data.aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn

    container_definitions = jsonencode([
        {
            name  = "dbt_container"
            image = var.dbt_image_uri

            command = [
                "bash",
                "-c",
                <<-EOF
                    "Bash code to run on the ECS instance is added here"
                EOF
            ]

            cpu       = 256
            memory    = 512
            essential = true
            logConfiguration = {
                logDriver = "awslogs"
                options = {
                    "awslogs-group"         = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.ecs_log_group.name
                    "awslogs-region"        = var.region
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix" = "ecs"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
}

Terraform ECS IAM configuration
# IAM Role
data "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
    name = "ecsTaskExecutionRole"
}

# IAM Policy
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ecs_task_execution_policy" {
    name        = "ecsTaskExecutionPolicy"
    description = "Policy for ECS task execution role"

    policy = jsonencode({
        Version = "2012-10-17",
        Statement = [
            {
                Action   = [
                    "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                    "logs:PutLogEvents",
                    "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                    "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                    "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                    "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                    "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                ],
                Effect   = "Allow",
                Resource = "*",
            },
        ],
    })
}

# IAM Role Policy Attachment
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_task_execution_attachment" {
    policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ecs_task_execution_policy.arn
    role       = data.aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.name
}

Terraform EventBridge IAM configuration
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role" {
    statement {
        effect = "Allow"

        principals {
            type        = "Service"
            identifiers = ["events.amazonaws.com"]
        }

        actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_events_role" {
    name               = "ecs_event_role"
    assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_events_run_task_with_any_role" {
    statement {
        effect    = "Allow"
        actions   = ["iam:PassRole"]
        resources = ["*"]
    }

    statement {
        effect    = "Allow"
        actions   = ["ecs:RunTask"]
        resources = [replace(aws_ecs_task_definition.dbt.arn, "/:\\d+$/", ":*")]
    }

}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "events_run_ecs_tasks_policy" {
    name        = "events-run-ecs-tasks-policy"
    description = "Policy for allowing ECS to assume role"
    policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_events_run_task_with_any_role.json
}

# IAM Role Policy Attachment
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_events_run_ecs_tasks_attachment" {
    policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.events_run_ecs_tasks_policy.arn
    role       = data.aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.name
}


In my experience this is always due to an incorrect IAM role assigned to EventBridge. It sounds like in the comments below that is exactly what you determined.

Disclosure: EventBridge PM here.
I reached out to the ECS team and we'd like to further debug this issue since the provided information is not sufficient to tell the root cause. Can you please raise a support request?

I just found the issue. In the terraform IAM EventBridge configuration I had attached the policy to the wrong role (EcsTaskExecutionRole), rather than the role assigned to EventBridge (ecs_event_role).
Not sure how to deal with the question posted now. Am I supposed to delete it or provide an answer?
